# How to allow external traffic and deny inter pod communication using network policy?

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress, kubernetes-networkpolicy

I am setting up my default namespace in my kubernetes cluster to allow incoming traffic from external nodes/hosts but deny any possible inter pod communication. I have 2 nginx pods which I want to completely isolate inside the cluster. Both pods are exposed with a service of the type nodePort and they are accessible from outside.

I first apply the following default deny network policy:

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: NetworkPolicy
metadata:
  name: default-deny
spec:
  podSelector: {}
  policyTypes:
  - Ingress
```

Then, I try allowing external traffic with the following network policy:

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: NetworkPolicy
metadata:
  name: allow-external
spec:
  podSelector: {}
  ingress:
    - from:
        - ipBlock:
            cidr: 192.168.0.0/16
```

But unfortunately I am not able to access the service either from outside and inside my cluster.

Running example in:
- macOS High Sierra v10.13.6
- minikube v1.5.2 --> with network plugin = cilium
- kubectl v1.16.2

How could I face this problem?

Comment: your cluster should include a pod CIDR. You can explicitely block the pod CIDR and allow all others

Comment: I have tried to look for my pod cidr with the command:
`kubectl cluster-info dump | grep -i cidr` 
and the outcome was the following: 
"clusterCIDR not specified, unable to distinguish between internal and external traffic".

Then I had a look at my the file located at: "~/.minikube/profiles/minikube/config.json"
and this was the output:
"MachineConfig": {
        ...
    },
    "KubernetesConfig": {
        ...
        "NetworkPlugin": "cni",
        "FeatureGates": "",
        "ServiceCIDR": "10.96.0.0/12",
        "ExtraOptions": null

Comment: Are you setting the CNI flag when launching the minikube?

Answer (score 2):

If you want to allow any incoming traffic to any pod except traffic that originates from your cluster you can use the "except" notation in a rule that allows traffic from all IP's. In below replace `172.17.1.0/24` with the cidr containing your pods:

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: NetworkPolicy
metadata:
  name: deny-all-internal
spec:
  podSelector: {}
  policyTypes:
  - Ingress
  ingress:
  - from:
    - ipBlock:
        cidr: 0.0.0.0/0
        except:
        - 172.17.1.0/24
```

Comment: I tried to look for my podCIDR but when I execute the following line of code I get this result. `kubectl cluster-info dump | grep -i cidr` --> `clusterCIDR not specified, unable to distinguish between internal and external traffic`.

Comment: I was able to set a podCIDR with the following command: `kubectl patch node minikube -p '{"spec":{"podCIDR":"10.33.12.0/24"}}'`. And when I apply the network policy you mentioned, all the internal traffic is blocked (perfect). But I cannot access the service exposed from my host machine. Although, the minikube node (VM) is able to `curl` the pods and the servives and get the answer back. However, I still get the message: **clusterCIDR not specified, unable to distinguish between internal and external traffic**